# php - get csv rows that contain a specific value in a specific column

Tags: php, csv, file-io

I have a csv file that contains states and names, I want to put state and name pairs into an array based on the state that I choose.

If I have a file:

```
    TX,Hank
    TX,Jane
    TX,Mark
    NY,Tom
    NY,Joe
    NC,Larry
```

I want to be able to get all pairs with NY in the first column and store them in an array:

```
    [0] => Array
      [0] => NY
      [1] => Tom

    [1] => Array
      [0] => NY
      [1] => Joe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = file(pathToFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$a = array_map(function ($i) { return explode(',', $i); }, $a);
// select only NY
$a = array_filter($a, function ($i) { return $i[0] == 'NY'; });
```

[demo](https://eval.in/558813)

Comment: Is $i supposed to be the variable that contains the state ID? If not, where do I specify which state I want?

Comment: I see, so this function turns the entire file into an array. So to get the value pairs for just NY, I have to get all of $a's elements that have $a[x][0] == 'NY'. Could you add that part to the answer?